# "if f is an injection, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all x in D(f) and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all y in R(f)"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that "if f is an injection, then $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ for all x in D(f) and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$ for all y in R(f)"

Does anyone could help keep? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $x$ belongs to $f^{-1}(f(x))$. If the latter has another element $z\neq x$, then $f(z)=f(x)$ violating injectivity. Thus, $f^{-1}(f(x))=\{x\}$.

On the other hand, the claim $f(f^{-1}(y))=\{y\}$ always holds, injectivity or not. All that is required is that $f$ is well-defined.

p.s. I have assumed that $R(f)\equiv\{f(x):x\in D(f)\}$.

Comment: No offence, but the proof looks not like a "proof", why x belongs to $f^{-1}(f(x))$?

Comment: No one here is expected to write something that you can directly submit as your homework. Fill in as many details as your instructor expects you to. As for $x\in f^{-1}(f(x))$, this is because $f(x)\in\{f(x)\}$.

Comment: Ok,thanks. By the way, it's not a homework question.